# El programa ejecuta un "if" cuando debería saltárselo

Tags: python, windows, pytube

Estoy haciendo un programa que descarga vídeos y playlists de youtube usando pytube, e hice un "input" para que el usuario decida si va a descargar una playlist o y un vídeo. Pero hay un fallo, ingreses lo que ingreses, el programa ejecuta la parte que debería ejecutar cuando ingresas "vídeo". Llevo un rato intentando encontrar el error, pero me parece que está todo bien... Por cierto, lo siento si el código es un poco largo. Y tened en cuenta que el código no está acabado, solo que lo ejecuté y encontré ese fallo.

```
import pytube
import os
import time

plvid=input("Vas a descargar una playlist o un vídeo? ")
if plvid.lower()=="vídeo" or "video":
    url=input("Introduce la URL del vídeo: ")
    video=pytube.YouTube(url)
    print(video.title)
    print("Cargando...")
    
    for i in video.streams:
        print("Itag: {} | Formato: {} | Resolución: {} ".format(i.itag, i.mime_type, 
i.resolution))
    
    itag = int(input("Ingrese el itag: "))
    print("Descargando...")
    video.streams.get_by_itag(itag).download("C:/Users/eddam/Downloads")
    print("La descarga ha finalizado.")


elif plvid.lower()=="playlist":
    url=input("Introduce la URL de la playlist: ")
    pl=pytube.Playlist(url)
    print(pl.title)
    print("Cargando...")

    for video in pl.videos:
        for i in video.streams:
            print("Itag: {} | Formato: {} | Resolución: {} ".format(i.itag, i.mime_type, 
i.resolution))

        itag = int(input("Ingrese el itag: "))

        print("Descargando...")
        video.streams.get_by_itag(itag).download("C:/Users/eddam/Downloads")

        print("La descarga ha finalizado.")
else:
    "Input incorrecto"
    time.sleep(10)
    os.exit(0)
```

print("El programa ha finalizado")

Comment: Error de tecleo, supongo que en `or "video"` Python asume _"video"_ como un valor [truthy](http://www.pybasico.com/python/python-valores-truthy-falsey/) y la expresión debería ser `if plvid.lower()=="vídeo" or plvid.lower()=="video":`

Comment: Sí, era eso. Gracias!!

Comment: Para ahorrar sintaxis puedes usar la librería re

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `if` siempre da `True` por la condición despues de `or`, debes poner las dos condiciones:

```
if (plvid.lower()=="vídeo" or plvid.lower()=="video")
```

Así compras la palabra con acento y sin acento que es lo que parece que quieres hacer.

Comment: También se puede usar una validación de membresía

Answer (score 0):

Un string de largo mayor a cero es `True` en Python.

La instrucción

```
if plvid.lower()=="vídeo" or "video":
```

siempre será `True`, ya que si la primera condición no se cumple (`plvid.lower()=="vídeo"`), la segunda siempre lo hara.

*Solución*

```
if plvid.lower()=="vídeo":
```