# ¿Cómo retornar un valor booleano desde una función?

Tags: python, funciones, booleano

Intento hacer una función que regresa el valor booleano `True`si n es par, y de no ser así que regrese valor booleano `False`.

No llevo mucho en Python, hasta ahorita tengo esto, pero no se de que manera puedo hacer los booleanos.

Si es de ayuda se toma como parámetro una variable llamada n la cual es numero entero.

```
def esPar(n):
resultado = False
if n:
    n = True
return n


resultado = esPar(6)
print(resultado)
```

Comment: Si este es el formato de tu código actual, te falta *indentarlo*

Comment: `def esPar(n): return True if n%2==0 else False`

Comment: `def par(n): return not n % 2`

Comment: la simplicidad ante todo :D

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [El programa ejecuta un "if" cuando debería saltárselo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/478418/el-programa-ejecuta-un-if-cuando-deber%c3%ada-salt%c3%a1rselo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada `resultado = False` es una variable definida dentro de la función pero no tiene funcionalidad, no le estas diciendo que hacer, solo esta definida y nada mas. Me imagino que quisiste usarla ya que también definiste la variable `resultado = esPar()` que contiene a la función. Si quisieses usar una variable dentro de una función, pero que esta definida por afuera de la misma, deberías usar `global resultado` al principio de la función. Si quieres puedes buscar más acerca de la `global`.

Por otro lado, el `if` de la función lo único que hace es cambiar el valor de `n` a `True`, y luego devuelve `n`, que es `True`, sea cual sea el parámetro (número) que le pasas al argumento `n`.

Lo que deberías hacer es algo como lo siguiente:

```
def es_par(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return True
    return False
```

En esta caso, el condicional `if` evalúa si el numero es divisible por 2. El operador `%` devuelve el resto de la división, y todos los números pares divididos por 2, deben dar resto igual a cero. En ese caso, si el resto es cero, devuelve `True`, caso contrario devuelve `False`.

Espero que te haya servido.

Saludos.